# On the top of / over / on... in this context

Tags: prepositions

**1.** I need to paint the wall **on the top of** the existing paint.

**2.** I need to paint the wall **over** the existing paint.

**3.** I need to paint the wall **on** the existing paint.

As a learner I'm not able to choose the correct one.

Please explain.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some revision, I would say that the first two sentences are okay, but the third is a bit awkward.

First of all, this simple sentence is just fine:

> I need to paint the wall.

If you're talking about existing paint, however, I would phrase it a bit differently:

> I need to paint **on top of** the (wall's) existing paint.
>   I need to paint **over** the (wall's) existing paint.

Normally, context will make it clear that you're talking about a wall in the first place—so you often wouldn't need to mention that. (Which is why I put it in brackets.) However, if it is mentioned, the sentence is clearer if the paint is main subject rather than the wall itself.

---

> I need to paint **on** the (wall's) existing paint.

The reason this doesn't sound completely normal is because it would be more likely interpreted as painting *a picture* (or something similar) on the wall rather than actually applying a coat of paint to the *entire* surface of the wall.

It's simply the case that when you *draw **on** a wall*, you are drawing on just a *portion* of wall. The same is true of *putting graffiti **on** a wall*. The association with *on* is, generally, one of using just a portion rather than the entire thing.

---

In choosing between **on top off** and **over**, *over* would be used in the specific context of deliberately covering up what's already there.

For instance:

> I hate that paint colour. I need to paint **over** it.

This implies that the purpose of painting is to *cover up* the existing paint that you don't like.

Meanwhile, *on top of* doesn't indicate a specific purpose in the same sense. It's just saying that when you apply new paint, you will do so without first removing the old paint.

---

I would personally tend to use *paint over* more than *paint on top of*, perhaps because it's applicable in more contexts, but I don't think there's a problem with using either one of them.